# how to sort in Tlistview based on subitem[x]

Tags: delphi, vcl, tlistview

How to sort in `tlistview` with data present in `subitem[x]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `SortType := stData` and write

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Compare(Sender: TObject; Item1, Item2: TListItem;
  Data: Integer; var Compare: Integer);
begin
  Compare := StrToInt(Item1.SubItems[x]) - StrToInt(Item2.SubItems[x])
end;
```

for instance. If compare is negative, Item1 should come before Item2; if compare is positive, the opposite applies. Thus this example, which assumes that SubItem[x] contains an integer, will sort the items according to the numerical value of SubItem[x].

If, on the other hand, SubItem[x] contains strings, then you can write

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Compare(Sender: TObject; Item1, Item2: TListItem;
  Data: Integer; var Compare: Integer);
begin
  Compare := AnsiCompareText(Item1.SubItems[x], Item2.SubItems[x]);
end;
```