# Delphi XE sort listview in datetime order

Tags: delphi, sorting

I am using the following code to populate a list view with the contents of a folder on windows and IOS.

```
procedure TTabbedForm.btnGetQuotesClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LList: TStringDynArray;
  i : Integer;
  LItem : TlistViewItem;
  windowsDir,AppPath : String;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  ListView1.Items.Clear;
{$IF DEFINED(MSWINDOWS)}
  windowsDir := TDirectory.GetCurrentDirectory;
  LList := TDirectory.GetFiles(windowsDir+'\quotes','*.txt');
  for i := 0 to Length(LList) - 1 do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(LList[i])  ;

    LItem := listView1.Items.Add;
    LItem.Text :=  LList[i];
  end;
{$ENDIF}
{$IF DEFINED(iOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}

  AppPath := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim;
  LList := TDirectory.GetFiles(AppPath,'*.txt');
  for i := 0 to Length(LList) - 1 do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(LList[i])  ;
    LItem := listView1.Items.Add;
    LItem.Text :=  LList[i];
  end;
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

I now need to sort the list in timestamp order / ascending and descending.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? Which aspect do you struggle with. XE does not support iOS. You mean XE8 or something close.

Comment: I also question why you repeat so much code. You should absolutely keep that to a minimum. Extract that which varies by platform. Do everything else in shared code.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @David Hefferman's comment, you want to look at refactoring your code so that the UI-dependent code (Get file list and get file age) is separate. I'd recommend making your own function that will return an array of FileName/FileDate records which can then be consumed by the loop in the calling code.

Regarding the How To Sort - you'll need to write a CustomSort routine - have a look at these other SO questions:

[how to sort in Tlistview based on subitem[x]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172028/how-to-sort-in-tlistview-based-on-subitemx)

[Sorting TListView Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573282/sorting-tlistview-columns)

If you don't do this then they'll either get sorted by Filename or by the DateTime field sorted as strings (i.e. it will go in order of 01/01/15 -> 11/01/15 -> 02/01/15 rather than 01/01/15 -> 02/01/15 -> 11/01/15)

Answer (score 0):

There is no overloaded version of GetFiles static method that accept a sorting function as parameter, so I think that in this case the only option would be to use the [FileAge](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.SysUtils.FileAge) ( `function FileAge(const FileName: string; out FileDateTime: TDateTime)` ), on each filename to get the last modified date and time of the file, and then on a second step ordering the files as you need ...